# Laravel Goutte Crawler timeout not works with "Too many redirects"

Tags: php, laravel, http, request, goutte

I am doing parsing remote websites with Laravel Goutte, and if remote website have error "Too many redirects" (I see it in Google Chrome), crawler just freeze and nothing happend.

```
use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

 try {
     $client = new Client(HttpClient::create(['timeout' => 5, 'max_redirects' => 1]));
     $client->request('GET', 'https://' . $domain_name);
}catch (\Exception $e){
     $this->error($e->getMessage());
}
```

I expect that if website will be not reached in 5 sec query will be droped and error will be catched, but for a very long time nothing happend (it just freeze on request row).
How I can handle websites with "Too many redirects" errors?

p.s. I don't know if I can post domain(tried with many domains that give this error) where I do query, if yes, I can post it in comments.

Comment: It's very weird, try to add some "dd()", var_dump, etc. I normallyvdon't do the `Client(HttpClient::create(['timeout`, but split it out in parts. Goutte is a client, that's a variable, then the http client is a variable. It gives a result. Catch it in a variable, etc, etc. You can var_dump those variables (or dd, which has better layout)

Comment: @UnderDog thanks, tried this `$httpClient = HttpClient::create(['timeout' => 5, 'max_redirects' => 0]); $httpClient->request('GET', 'https://' . $Domain->domain_name);` and it returned error `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently returned for {domain}`, but why it doesn't work with Goutte, strange. Anyway thanks for help.